# How to check migration status?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

In Rails, I can run:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

But how about Laravel? How would I know which migrations will run when I do:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I am on a production server, and I need to make sure that I won't break things.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's the exact same way with `artisan`, just add `:status`:

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

---

In the future you can run just `php artisan` and it will list all available commands with a short description for each one. If you want more details about a command, like usage and what options it accepts, you can run `php artisan help [command]`. So for your command it would be:

```
php artisan help migrate:status
```

Comment: Thanks, although its strange as I googled it but didn't find anything before I post the question..

Comment: You're very welcome. Indeed, there are no specific results in Google about this subject, there is only [an article](https://sheepy85.wordpress.com/2014/09/19/database-seed-migration-in-laravel-5-0/) down in the results about migrations that mentions it. The good part is that this question was already indexed by Google, so it can be found by future searches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 8 as alternate version then use below command to check.

> php80 artisan migrate:status

Check list of PHP Migration command:

> php80 artisan list